# String manipulation in java

Tags: java

I have below string :

```
String str="<div><select id=\"test2\"><option id=\"1\" value=\"one\" selected><option id=\"2\" value=\"two\"/></select";
```

Based on string "two",avove string manipulated to below:

```
String resultstr="<div><select id=\"test2\"><option id=\"1\" value=\"one\" ><option id=\"2\" value=\"two\" selected/></select";
```

How to do the above process.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: I can show you how to do that conversion, but without context, what I show you likely won't help you solve your problem in a greater context. What needs to stay constant? What needs to be able to vary? **EDIT:** Also, this text comes from an XML-based document, but you seem to be parsing it as a raw text file. You might want to consider using the built-in libraries to handle XML's, as it will make your code much more extensible.

Comment: @T.k:thi is not xml.Here i want ,based on String "two",i should able to modify the original string.

Comment: @@T.k:Is it possible to with API like Xpath or any thing..

Answer (score 3):

Look into the [String.replace functions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), e.g. `str = str.replace("this", "with_that")`;

Answer (score 0):

String.replace() example

```
String str = "<div><select id=\"test2\"><option id=\"1\" value=\"one\" selected><option id=\"2\" value=\"two\"/></select";
String resultstr = str.replace(" selected", "").replace("value=\"two\"" , "value=\"two\" selected");
System.out.println(resultstr);
```

Comment: first replace is fine .but second replace is not way to do it.Based on string i want to insert selected.